# Get and set the certificate used by Exchange with port 587 (submission)

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, tls

Sometimes users want to use POP3/SMTP with Exchange. They report that there is certificate issue with sending mail as the server uses the domain certificate for encryption. Of course I could install the root CA but I was hoping there is a way to send over a CA from a trusted root. I would like to see where this is set so I can change it to use a third-party (trusted root CA) certificate. Is this possible with Exchange 2007? How can I get/set the certificate it uses on port 587?